# Cannot serialize JPA bean due to presence of proxies

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jersey, jax-rs

I am trying to expose an object as XML using JAX-RS.

I have a class called `Client` and I am returning its instance like this:

```
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    @GET
    @Produces("application/xml")
    @Path("/{clientId}.xml")
    public Client getCleintAsXML(@PathParam("clientId") int clientId) {
        Client c = em.find(Client.class, clientId);
        return c;
    }
```

But the `Client` object has a list of `Group` objects and `Group` object in turn has list of other objects.

When JAX-RS tries to serialize `Client` object it traverses the entire object graph. When it ecounters Hibernate proxy for `groups` the code breaks because lazy loading works only inside the transaction.

Fair enough, so I load `groups` eagerly before exiting the transaction.

But it still fails because each `Group` object in turn has one-to-many relations i.e. even more proxied lists.

I don't even need them in the output. I realize that my problem would be solved if these proxies are removed i.e set to null.

I don't want to manually set them to null as this is error prone and not maintainable. Is there a way to do this automatically?

Or can I tell hibernate to not use proxies for this particular query? Or only use proxies 1 level deep?

I am using Hibernate behind JPA. As far as possible I don't want any direct references to Hibernate.

I found a dozen classes written by different users to get rid of the proxies. Is there a standard way to do this? If this is such a common problem, I guess, there would be a standard solution.

Comment: Hibernate POJOs are not serializable. For example GWT has problems with that, see here https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/using_gwt_with_hibernate You're not using GWT, but is it possible you have a similar problem in your environment?

Comment: No that wasn't it. Hibernate uses proxies which delay the fetching of data till the time the data is actually required. That fails if object is detached. I resolved this by removing all uninitialized HibernateProxies using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by removing uninitialized hibernate proxies. This removes only collections as that was my requirement. Feel free to suggest edits for benefit of other users.

First cut:

```
import java.beans.PropertyDescriptor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils;
import org.hibernate.Hibernate;
import org.hibernate.collection.PersistentCollection;
import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;

public class HibernateProxyCleaner {

    public static Object clean(Object bean) {
        return clean(bean,0,2);
    }

    public static Object clean(Collection bean, int depth, int maxDepth) {
        if (bean == null || depth>maxDepth)
            return bean;

        for (Object o : (Collection) bean) {
            clean(o,depth,maxDepth);
        }

        return bean;
    }

    public static Object clean(Object bean, int depth, int maxDepth) {
        if (bean == null || depth>maxDepth)
            return bean;

        try {
            PropertyDescriptor[] pda = BeanUtils.getPropertyDescriptors(bean
                    .getClass());

            for (PropertyDescriptor pd : pda) {
                Object o = PropertyUtils.getProperty(bean, pd.getName());
                if (o != null) {
                    if (o instanceof PersistentCollection) {
                        if (PropertyUtils.isReadable(bean, pd.getName()) && PropertyUtils.isWriteable(bean, pd.getName())) {
                            if (!Hibernate.isInitialized((PersistentCollection) o)) {
                                o = null;
                                PropertyUtils.setProperty(bean, pd.getName(), o);
                            }

                        }
                    } else {
                        clean(o,depth+1,maxDepth);
                    }
                }


            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bean;
    }

}
```